# Replace ohai-plugin with...?

Tags: chef-infra

We've been using the `ohai` plugin for our windows servers. The plugin detects/collects the info on if there is any windows update available and/or if the server needs a reboot

```
ohai_plugin 'ohai_windows_updates'
ohai_plugin 'ohai_windows_reboot'
```

Now I've read that ohai is deprecated. I tried to find out how we can collect such information otherwise but I couldn't find it. Maybe you can help?

Comment: Not sure about the "ohai plugin". Though [ohai](https://docs.chef.io/ohai/) itself seems to be supported.

Comment: The ohai plugin is part of the ohai cookbook. And the cookbook is deprecated:
https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/ohai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the authers point out in the cookbook readme:

> This cookbook has been deprecated as all functionality here is now
> built into the Chef Infra Client itself. The ohai_hint resource now
> ships in Chef Infra Client and any plugins can be installed by placing
> them in an ohai directory within a cookbook in your runlist.

So the [`ohai_hint` resource](https://docs.chef.io/resources/ohai_hint/) is now available since Chef Client v14.0.

And [about cookbooks](https://docs.chef.io/cookbooks/) document says that `ohai/` folder in cookbook can be used as source of custom Ohai plugins written to load additional information about your nodes to be used in recipes. This requires Chef Infra Server (not Client!) v12.18.14 or later.

So to continue to use your plugins you need to make sure your Chef Infra Server is at least v12.18.14 and move plugin files into `ohai/` folder of some cookbook.

Or leave everything as is for now. Because deprecation in this case means just stopping of further development - the cookbook will not we deleted. You can continue using it, if for some reason you cannot upgrade your Chef Server.